# Revert display mapping in whitespace-mode?

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I would like to make the display mappings and face attributes to be updated if i were to change them after invoking `M-x whitespace-mode`. I would like to do so to make the code below work. If I don't include the `add-hook` and try setting the faces before I enter `whitespace-mode` it tells me that the face is invalid.

```
;; configure custom whitespace faces
(add-hook 'whitespace-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (set-face-attribute 'whitespace-space   nil :background nil :foreground color)
  (set-face-attribute 'whitespace-tab     nil :background nil :foreground color)
  (set-face-attribute 'whitespace-newline nil :background nil :foreground color)
  (whitespace-reload) ;; what i want to do
  )))
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For faces, variables and functions that do not exist yet because a library has not been loaded, options include, but are not limited to: `eval-after-load` or `require`. You may wish to add more details regarding what you seek so that the question/answer is helpful to other forum participants.  At the present time, the question and *your* answer do not appear to be very *helpful* to anyone else (in my opinion, that is).

Answer (score 0):

Just using `whitespace-mode` in .emacs worked.

```
;; ... add-hook 'n all
(whitespace-mode 1)(whitespace-mode 0)
```